# Simple x86 linux assembly program returning unexpected value

Tags: assembly

Here is a simple program that should find the minimum of data_items. a 0 is used to terminate the block of memory. %ebx is tracking the current minimum and 0 should never get copied into it because of the `je` instruction. And yet, this program is returning 0 to the OS and not 3.

```
.section .data

data_items:
 .long 3,67,34,222,45,75,54,34,44,222,11,66,0

.section .text

.globl _start

_start:
 movl $0, %edi          #move 0 into the index register
 movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax  #load the first byte of data
 movl %eax, %ebx        #first item, so its smalles, ebx tracks smallest

 start_loop:
  cmpl $0, %eax         #check if we hit the end
  je loop_exit
  incl %edi
  movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax
  cmpl %ebx, %eax
  jge start_loop

  movl %eax, %ebx
  jmp start_loop

 loop_exit:
  movl $1, %eax
  int $0x80
```

Edit: Correct code here:

```
.section .data

data_items:
 .long 3,67,34,222,45,75,54,34,44,222,11,66,0

.section .text

.globl _start

_start:
 movl $0, %edi          #move 0 into the index register
 movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax  #load the first byte of data
 movl %eax, %ebx        #first item, so its biggest, ebx tracks biggest

 start_loop:
  incl %edi
  movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax
  cmpl $0, %eax
  je loop_exit

  cmpl %ebx, %eax
  jge start_loop

  movl %eax, %ebx
  jmp start_loop

 loop_exit:
  movl $1, %eax
  int $0x80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic isn't right.

In C code, your program looks like

```
edi = 0;
eax = data_items[edi];
ebx = eax;
while(eax != 0) {
    eax = data_items[++edi];
    if(eax < ebx) ebx = eax;
}
exit(ebx);
```

The problem is that you load `eax` then immediately store it as the minimum. If `eax = 0`, you store it as the minimum (because it is), and only then do you break.

Comment: i got stuck somewhere in the at&t syntax

Comment: Due to having to use crappy disassemblers from time to time, I've learned to read AT&T syntax. I still strongly prefer Intel syntax, obviously...

Comment: Thanks, i moved the 0 check inside the loop to be after eax gets set.